# find shortest path between 2 vertices using BFS algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, shortest-path

I have this question for homework:

prove/disprove:

A. Given an unintentional bound graph G (V, E) and a minimum spanning tree for this graph, and 2 vertices u, v, the shortest path between u and v in graph G can be found by performing BFS on the tree T.

B. Given a directed graph G (V, E) with weights and vertex s. The number of arcs in the shortest distance tree of this graph from the origin of s is the | V | -1.

I think that's true but can't prove it.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

A. Not true, the minimum spanning tree does not contain all the shortest paths. example:
[image]

The MST is the black edges (weight=1) the red edge (weight=2) is the shortest path between its nodes.

B. True, suppose you have a shortest paths graph with *|V|* edges, than there is a node *v* with at least two path from *s* (let *v* be the closest node to *s* with that property), in that case you can remove one of the incoming edges of *v* without changing the weights of the paths to all the nodes

Comment: The answer for B was false also.